# Git rebase a branch on another after parent branch is merged to master

Tags: git, git-commit, git-rebase

If I have `branch_1` forked out of `master` with let's say 2 commits.

Next, I made `branch_2` forked out of `branch_1`.
On `branch_2` I have made changes which are not in the area `branch_1`. I of course have changes from `branch_1` included here but I have not touched those changes.

Now let's say `branch_1` merges into master.

Next, on `branch_2` I do `git pull upstream master --rebase` to rebase `branch_2` on top of master so that commits from `branch_1` disappear from commit history of `branch_2`. I should not get merge conflicts here. Right? But I do in the same lines of code which were changed on `branch_1`. This is strange! Is this expected?

Comment: git pull upstream master --rebase

Comment: I have squashed commits on `branch_1`. May be thats the reason

Comment: but did you make changes to branch_1(add a commits)  before you create the branch_2 from branch_1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption about what the rebase would do is valid, **if git knows the relationship between `branch_1` and `branch_2`**. Your problem is that you **threw away that relationship** by rebasing or squashing `branch_1`.

With a true merge, your commit graph would look like this (where "M" is the merge commit when you merged branch_1 into master):

```
            master
              |
              v
... <- A <--- M
        \    /
         <- B <- C
            ^    ^
            |    |
       branch_1 branch_2
```

Then, when you rebased branch_2 onto master, git would find that commit B is already reachable from master (as a parent of commit M), so wouldn't include it in the list of commits to replay.

However, when you squashed branch_1, you created this (where "BS" is the result of squashing branch_1):

```
            master
              |
              v
... <- A <--- BS
        \    
         <- B <- C
            ^    ^
            |    |
       branch_1 branch_2
```

Now when you ask to rebase branch_2 on master, it finds that commit B is *not* reachable from master (commit BS), so *includes* it in the list of commits to replay. If commit B was actually multiple commits, it will apply them one by one, and since the changes have already happened in BS, you'll get conflicts when it does so.

The solution (other than using true merges from now on ) is to be more explicit about what you want to rebase, by either:

- Using an interactive rebase (`git rebase -i upstream/master`) and manually deleting the commits from branch_1 from the todo list
- Using the three-argument form of `git rebase`, "rebase old_base old_tip --onto new_base": `git rebase branch_1 branch_2 --onto upstream/master`

Comment: Should this:
'where "M" is the merge commit when you merged branch_1 into branch_2'
read:
'where "M" is the merge commit when you merged branch_1 into master'

Comment: @LukePurnell I think you are right, well spotted, I've edited that.

Answer (score 1):

I have reproduced your situation like in the first image below.

Notice here I have the following naming :

master ==> main

branch_1 ==> br1

branch_2 ==> br2

And the br1 is merged into main

And the head is at the main branch (*)

[image]

To rebase br2 into main, you should :

```
git checkout br2
git rebase main
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To rebase branch_2 from master, after branch_1 has been merged, do:

```
git checkout branch_2
git rebase branch_1 branch_2
git rebase --onto master branch_1 branch_2
```